# Question about proof of euler's criterion

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

When a is quadratic residue of the odd prime p, we arrived to the conclusion $(p-1)! \equiv -a^{{p-1}/2}\pmod{p}$. How does that imply $a^{{p-1}/2} \equiv 1\pmod{p}$

Comment: [Wilson's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) answers this question. See [Euler's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) for a more general result.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** recall [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem): $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$.

Comment: Right, I forgot  that one.